# input redirection to echo

Tags: linux, io, echo

I'm fairly new to bash/linux and was trying to do the following:

```
echo < test.txt
```

where test.txt just contains a bunch of text. The problem is this just prints a blank line to the terminal output.

I understand I could just use `cat` but I'm trying to understand why redirecting input to `echo` isn't working.

Comment: Check [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63658/redirecting-the-content-of-a-file-to-the-command-echo)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo < test.txt
```

Will not work because `echo` operates on a format string, not redirected file input (i.e. `stdin`). What you want is `cat`

```
cat test.txt
```

`cat` short for concatenate will `cat` test.txt to `stdout`. **note:** its companion `tac` will write `test.txt` to `stdout` in **reverse**.